# How to delete all comments in docx file with OpenXML Powertools

Tags: c#, openxml, docx, openxml-powertools

I cannot find an example of how to delete all comments using OpenXML Powertools. Is this functionality included similar to the acceptrevisions or does it require a custom implementation?

I am currently doing it with the wordprocessingdocument class developed by Microsoft but the powertools seem to account for more xml structure than I have expertise on.

Thanks